# dependencias incumplidas con python3-sphinx

Tags: dependencias

al querer instalar una polybar para mi sistema operativo (parrot os) me salta este error

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
python3-sphinx : Depende: python3-pygments (>= 2.13) pero 2.7.1+dfsg-2.1 va a ser instalado

Alguna idea de como pueda arreglarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hola Anthony me ha ocurrido lo mismo, no sé si has podido solucionarlo utilizando Parrot OS, yo finalmente he descargado Kali Linux y me ha funcionado.